# How do I change the names of fields in an express GET response?

Tags: javascript, api, rest, express, get

Right now, I have working code as follows for an express API:

```
router.get('/Find', function(req, res, next){
    Dog.findOne({
        'Date_Time_Competed': req.query.Competed
    }).then(function(dog){
        res.send({
            'Breed': dog.breed,
            'Age': dog.ageInYears,
            'Owner': dog.owner
        })
    }).catch(next);
});
```

This code makes a call to a MongoDB database and finds the breed, ageInYears, and owner categories and returns them in a JSON format associated with the categories Breed, Age, and Owner.

I now want to do a .find() call to get multiple entries, but I can't seem to figure out how to change the names of the fields when I have multiple entries.

Right now, this is what I'm trying. It works, but I can't figure out how to change the names of the fields. (NOTE: There are more fields in the DB for each entry that I don't want to use, that's why I'm not specifying certain fields).

```
router.get('/Find', function(req, res, next){
    Dog.find({
        'Date_Time_Competed': req.query.Competed
    }, 'breed ageInYears owner')
    .then(function(dog){
        res.send(dog);
    }).catch(next);
});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
router.get('/Find', function(req, res, next){
    Dog.aggregate([
        {$match: {Date_Time_Competed: req.query.Competed}},
        {$project: {
            _id: 0,
            "Breed": "$breed",
            "Age": "$ageInYears",
            "Owner": "$owner",
        }}
    ]).then(function(dog){
        res.send(dog);
    }).catch(next);
});
```